# html template files to populate php variables

Tags: php, html, variables, module

I am creating custom pages in phpbb and do not understand

```
<table class="table1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>{L_EMAIL}</th>
</tr>
<!-- BEGIN block_name -->
<tr class="<!-- IF block_name.S_ROW_COUNT is even -->bg1<!-- ELSE -->bg2<!-- ENDIF -->">
    <td>{block_name.ID}</td>
    <td>{block_name.NAME}</td>
    <td>{block_name.EMAIL}</td>
</tr>
<!-- END block_name -->
```

I do not understand the following

```
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>{L_EMAIL}</th>
```

Where is it getting its values, and how values are sent to such files.
Where can I find some examples?

Comment: that's not php. it's maybe a templating engine built on TOP of php, but that's not php.

Comment: whatever that is, I need a hello world! example with all minimum required files and file structure

Answer (score 2):

First of all i would like to tell you that its the plain html, the {L_NAME} is getting replaced from you PHP script. It works something like this:-

**Step1:** my_html_file.html

First of the below written code is HTML. The purpose of writing **{L_NAME}** 
is to replace the **{L_NAME}** with the user's last name with any PHP variable's value.

```
<th>ID</th>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>{L_EMAIL}</th>
```

**Step2:** my_php_file.php

Now you can use the following code to replace the **{L_NAME}** like this:-

```
$name = 'Dinesh Singh Rawat';
$html_content = file_get_contents('my_html_file.html');
echoh $newStr = str_replace('{L_NAME}', $name, $html_content);
```

**OUTPUT:**

**ID**  **NAME**  **DINESH SINGH RAWAT**

Hope you are getting.